# How to get variable from environment laravel in all code

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i was try to get environment variabel, to get APP_URL from .env,
but always return null, but when use random string it show,

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
    
    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return env('APP_URL');
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YkB5.png

Comment: the right way is to use `config('app.url')` not `env()` directly. do larter `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Laravel official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

> You may easily access your configuration values using the global
> config function from anywhere in your application. The configuration
> values may be accessed using "dot" syntax, which includes the name of
> the file and option you wish to access. A default value may also be
> specified and will be returned if the configuration option does not
> exist

In your case:

```
$value = config('app.url');

// Retrieve a default value if the configuration value does not exist...
$value = config('app.url', 'somedefaulturl');
```

Your code should look as:

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
    
    public function getUrlAttribute()
    {
        return config('app.url');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to get it from the model when you can just get it from everywhere and anywhere in your code?

```
$url = config('app.url');
```

is enough for you. Best of success

Comment: Because I created for attachment file so need base URL + file_located